# How can i call a member function pointer from another member function?

Tags: c++, pointers, pointer-to-member

I have a class which has a data memeber which store a member function pointer. The pointer points to different member functions in different time. I would like to call this funcion pointer from another member function. How can i do this?

```
class A {

  void (A::*fnPointer)() = nullptr;

  void callerMemberFunction(){
    fnPointer = &A::someMemberFunction;  // Store the function
    (*fnPointer)(); // I would like to call the function. How can i do?
  }

  void someMemberFunction(){ ... }

}
```

Comment: `(*this.*fnPointer)();`

Comment: I know this doesn't answer the question because you are specifically asking about a function pointer, nevertheless a more modern approach would be to use `std::function<void()> fn;` as the member variable, then assign a lambda to it: `fn = [this](){someMemberFunction();};` and call it simply using `fn()`. `std::function` is part of the STL and can be included using `#include <functional>`.

Comment: @DavidWright -- in many cases, `std::function` adds overhead with no corresponding benefit. `std::function` is designed to manage impedance mismatches, for example, providing an interface that can be called with an argument of type `long`, and applying an underlying function that takes `int` or `double` or anything else that `long` can be converted to. If you don't need that kind of conversion, you don't need `std::function`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify which object to call the function on:

```
(this->*fnPointer)();
```

Comment: Such an odd syntaxis!